# ASP.NET 4.5 - Redirect to specific landing page on Load or Application Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a 4.5 Website with Master Page. I have 2 pages Home and Dashboard apart from few other pages . I have provided an option for the users to set a specific page out of these 2 as their landing page ( default page) . This option will save the selection in DB and redirects to the appropriate page next time when the user launches the Application.

Note : No login page in this website. Just uses Windows authentication.

Problem : 
1. I cannot write this code to check the configured landing page from DB and redirect in Home Page since clicking on "HOME" page from any other page will again redirect the user to the configured landing page only. 
2. When i wrote the code in Session Start of Global.asax it works fine. However when a Session timeout happens before I could redirect them to the Session timeout page this redirect to landing page is getting executed.

Can anyone please provide me some hint / best practice as where I can write this logic to achieve the above said !!!

Thanks.

Comment: you can change the homepage link in every pages to the user landing page URL.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Kienct.. I do not want them to go to thier landing page when their intent is to go to Home Page. The landing page redirect is meant only on Lauching the web application. Otherwise they are free to move to Home page or any other page.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your intent, in that case, you might want to consider redirect them only after they log in. Make more sense to me.

Comment: Have you thought about using a non-persistent cookie (i.e. no expiration date) to indicate if the initial redirection has already occurred? Then you could put the redirect logic in your home page and it would only occur the first time (until the browser was closed and opened again).